# Why doesn't the 'i' increment up through every iteration of the loop? (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm new to this method of iteration, why doesn't the 'i' increment up through every iteration of the loop?
The goal of this snippet is to remove duplicates from the sorted array.

```
int main()
{
vector<int> nums{ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4 };

int length = 0;

for (int i : nums)
{
    if (nums[i] != nums[i + 1])
    {
        length += 1;
        cout << nums[i] << endl;
    }
    i++;
}
return length;
}
```

Comment: Because `i` is the element itself and not the index. This isn't JavaScript.

Comment: right. Got it, ty.

Comment: it's `range based for loop`, see the [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), it has some example at bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` will take the values from the vector, 0, 0, 1, 1, etc ...

It doesn't take on index value (positions)

If you had

```
vector<int> nums{ 0, 0, 1, 10000, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4 };
```

You'd get a crash.

Comment: ah yes, ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the for loop wrong.
Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nums.size()-1; i++)
{
  if (nums[i] == nums[i + 1])
  {
    nums.erase(i + nums.begin()); // if duplicate, the second value would be removed
    i--;
  }
}
```

Also if you want to get the length of the vector, you could use:

```
nums.size();
```